# Prevent autocompletion input react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an interface where the user can change their password and related information. When accessing this page, I find myself with the input password auto completed by the browser, I tried all the possible attributes: autoComplete="off" on the form tag and also on the inputs. But nothing works, I had to dig more in details and I realized that the value of the input password is filled but goes through my setState of this input. So I found a way to block auto completion, when the browser tries to set the default value.

I have a state variable isFirstInteraction which is true, at the beginning, when the browser tries to modify the input through my setState function, I check if isFirstInteraction is true, if so I do not modify the value of the state, otherwise I modify it.

Now I'm here to make sure it will always work the same. Is there a case where the browser will not make this first interaction for example? This could degrade the user experience. Is my technique 100% functional?

This is the code :

```
export default function AccountGeneralDatas({ user }) {
    const [fields, setFields] = useState(null)
    const [isFirstInteraction, setIsFirstInteraction] = useState(true)

    const onHandleChangeBasicInput = (event) => {
        if (isFirstInteraction) {
            setIsFirstInteraction(false)
        } else {
            const name = event.target.name
            const value = event.target.value
            let fieldsChanged = { ...fields }

            fieldsChanged[name] = value
            setFields(fieldsChanged)
        }
    }

    return (
        <Form className="account-general-datas">
            {fields && (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            onChange={onHandleChangeBasicInput}
                            type="email"
                            name={AccountGeneralDatasForm.EMAIL.name}
                            value={fields[AccountGeneralDatasForm.EMAIL.name]}
                        />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Label>New Password</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            onChange={onHandleChangeBasicInput}
                            type="password"
                            name={AccountGeneralDatasForm.NEW_PASSWORD.name}
                            value={fields[AccountGeneralDatasForm.NEW_PASSWORD.name]}
                        />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Label>Confirm password</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            onChange={onHandleChangeBasicInput}
                            name={AccountGeneralDatasForm.CONFIRM_PASSWORD.name}
                            value={fields[AccountGeneralDatasForm.CONFIRM_PASSWORD.name]}
                            type="password"
                        />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Button type="submit" className="btn btn-general btn-little-rounded btn-special-long">
                       Save
                    </Button>
                </React.Fragment>
            )}
        </Form>
    )
}
```

Comment: autoComplete="off" should work. Is it react bootstrap you are using?

Comment: Yes that's what i use